# Angular Reactive form setValue setting string to number input type, input box empty but string value is assigned in controlls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

Angular Reactive form setValue setting string to number input type, input box empty but string value is assigned in controlls, validation required is not working

This is Form Controller

```
    ngOnInit() {
       this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
         name: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
         age: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
       }
    }

    patchAge(){
      this.profileForm.controls["age"].setValue("somethingString");
    }
```

This is template

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <input
      type="text"
      formControlName="name"
    />
    <input
      type="number"
      formControlName="age"
    />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only validator your `age` control has is `required`, which means the value cannot be empty, so the value can be anything.

Even though you are setting the input as `type=number`, this is just a HTML validation, you are expecting your form object to be aware of this.

```js
patchAge(){
  this.profileForm.get("age")?.patchValue("somethingString");
  console.log('Is my form valid?: ', this.form.valid) // TRUE
}
```

That's why your form valid state is TRUE, because it has indeed a value.

So the solution for this will be to add another validation to `age`

```js
age: new FormControl("", [
  Validators.required, 
  Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/) // only numbers
]),
```

If you print right from the beginning the valid state of your form, it should be `false`

Answer (score 0):

try to change "" to 0 as follows `age: new FormControl("", Validators.required)` to `age: new FormControl(0, Validators.required)` on ngOnInit()